# ungrabbing keys

Tags: xorg, keyboard

I have somehow managed to get my keyboard only to work and be able to select with the mouse cursor, only when the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> keys are held.
How can I undo this?
I have tried System -> Preferences -> Keyboard but nothing appears there to resolve this.

---

**Edit**:

I can only enter text or select anything (even opening a new tab in web browser), only if the shift and control keys are held. once the selection is "active" then I can type normally, until the next time I need to type, etc..
Below as recommended:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
root 0x1ad, subw 0x0, time 2238759, (-435,502), root:(312,552),
state 0x11, keycode 38 (keysym 0x41, A), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (41) "A"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

---

**Edit**:

Pressing (and holding) the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd> key has a similar action as to holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> are held simultaneously).

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Comment: I don't understand what's happening. Do you mean that unless `Shift` and `Ctrl` are both held, nothing happens when you press a key? Or that your keyboard acts as if they are both held all the time? Are you still able to type commands into the machine? If you can, run `xev` and tell us what it displays when you press the `A` key.

Comment: @Stuck: You can edit your question to add more information; don't write an answer for that. A moderator has converted your answer to a comment, and I've merged it into your question so that the `xev` output would be more readable.

Comment: @Gilles Adding it to the question was a good idea; I ended up deleting the converted comment since it's useless now

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your system believes that you're holding down the mod2 modifier, so try pressing and releasing the corresponding key. Modifiers other than `Shift` and `Ctrl` don't have standard assignments, so I can't tell you what the corresponding key is. `xmodmap -pm` would tell you, but try pressing and releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

(I'm basing this on `state 0x11`, which I think means Shift + mod2, but I'm not completely sure that's what it means. But the symptoms do look like a missed key release event.)

**Update**: The output from `xmodmap -pm` shows that mod2 is Num Lock, so try toggling Num Lock off.